# how to use face_recognition in google colab with drive data

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, face-recognition, drive

I cannot use the face_recogniton library in google colab. I tried it in env and without env but it is not accepting the path for data. its showing invalid syntax
please answer this question or share link eated to this.
thankyou.

code  ![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSUKi.png
 error ![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFuoU.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your image i see that you need to chagne the path given.

Colab doesnt understand folder names with spaces. So you need to use My Drive as follows

gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_working_folder/nb_history.ipynb

Please accept the answer if it works for you.